# Magento advanced newsletter hide email fields when customer logged in

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have found a problem under this extension:

If the user is not logged he can see all input field (name, email...), but if he is logged all inputs disappears and he can only see the subscription button which only subscribe his account e-mail.

I need guest users and logged users seeing the same form! Both need to be able to choose any email they want to subscribe.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Enable Magento Template Path Hints](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-template-path-hints-magento) - to find the path to the form template
2. Comment out the code that check if customer is login (i.e `$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()`)

Comment: @R.S. please provide path for this. i have not found proper path for comment this condition.

Comment: I do not have that module install so I can not provide you path, but if you just turn on 'Template Path Hints' you will be able to figure it out.